# How to add DOCTYPE when creating xml using "xmlbuilder" npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

Is there a way to add !DOCTYPE in an XML file using 'xmlbuilder' package.

Like add like

```
<!DOCTYPE IAD.IF.ESTATE.FORRENT SYSTEM "http://www.finn.no/dtd/IADIF-estateforrent71.dtd">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the `DOCTYPE` declaration using the `sysID` property when creating your root xml element.

**Example:**

```js
const builder = require('xmlbuilder', { encoding: 'utf-8' });

// Create the root xml element and define the DOCTYPE declaration
const root = builder.create('IAD.IF.ESTATE.FORRENT', {
  'sysID': 'http://www.finn.no/dtd/IADIF-estateforrent71.dtd',
});

root.ele('HEAD')
    .ele('PARTNER').txt('Foobar');

// ...

const xmlString = root.end({ 
  pretty: true
});

console.log(xmlString);
```

---

**Output:**

The example above prints the following XML fragment:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE IAD.IF.ESTATE.FORRENT SYSTEM "http://www.finn.no/dtd/IADIF-estateforrent71.dtd">
 <IAD.IF.ESTATE.FORRENT>
   <HEAD>
     <PARTNER>Foobar</PARTNER>
   </HEAD>
 </IAD.IF.ESTATE.FORRENT>
```

---

Additional information can be found in the *XML-Prolog* section of the [docs](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki/XML-Prolog)